# css media max-width does not work properly

Tags: css

I am trying to manipulate the view when the screen is less than 600px.
for some reason, it does not work for this width, it only works for higher width.

*For testing purposes when the screen is less than 600px I am trying to hide the entire body.

Here is my code:
https://codepen.io/eyalankri/pen/qzbdVm

**if you change this:**

```
 @media (max-width: 600px) {
        body{display: none}
  }
```

**To This:**

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
        body{display: none}
  }
```

**It will work.**

Can someone help me understand why it does not work for 600px ?
Thanks.

Comment: Works for me in your codepen

Comment: Same here. When I test your codepen, the body isn't displayed when the viewport is <600px.

Comment: *" I am trying to hide the entire body."* - Why? What purpose would that serve?

Comment: Seems to work fine. If I load up device view in Chrome tools and then resize the viewport to <600px the result content disappears.

Comment: @Paulie_D: it's just for testing

Comment: It is important to remember that CSS overrides are read as an English text, left-to-right, top-to-bottom. Make sure there are no `!important` overrides and that your media query is one of the last overrides. Also, bare in mind that inline CSS is also top-priority.

Comment: I can see the body on my mobile device? it's not hidden. what I am missing?

Comment: You're probably missing the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: @ZohirSalak: Thank you. that works!